# Парсер для XML документа

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, xml

Нужно написать парсер для XML документа (на Python):

```
<ns2:export xmlns:ns5="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/base/1" xmlns="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/types/1" xmlns:ns6="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/EPtypes/1" xmlns:ns7="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/printform/1" xmlns:ns8="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/control99/1" xmlns:ns2="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/export/1" xmlns:ns3="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/pprf615types/1" xmlns:ns4="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/common/1">
<ns2:fcsNotificationEF schemeVersion="8.2">
<id>16950858</id>
<purchaseNumber>0111200000918000410</purchaseNumber>
<directDate>2018-07-05T16:55:52+03:00</directDate>
<docPublishDate>2018-07-05T16:55:59.225+03:00</docPublishDate>
<docNumber>№ИИ1</docNumber>
<href>
http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/notice/ea44/view/common-info.html?regNumber=0111200000918000410
</href>
<printForm>
<url>
http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/notice/printForm/viewXml.html?noticeId=16950858
</url>
```

Это не полный XML файл. Все нужные элементы содержаться в `ns2:fcsNotificationEF.`

Вот что удалось мне написать, нужно вытащить элементы `id` и `href`, `url`. При выводе `url` появляется пустая трока. Да и сам метод я думаю не качественный, так как ссылается на индекс элемента. Как сделать, чтобы напрямую ссылаться на элемент без индексов?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('xml_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

id_z = root[0][0].text
href_z = root[0][5].text
url_z = root[0][6].text

print ('id:', id_z)
print ('href:', PublishDate)
print ('url:', url_z)
```

Пожалуйста оставляйте ответы развернутыми, а то я новичок в Python и вообще в программировании. Благодарю за ответы.

Comment: id, href в xml вижу, а где url?

Comment: @gil9red добавил часть кода с url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример с `BeautifulSoup` и поиском через `css-селекторы`:

```
xml_str = """\
<ns2:export xmlns:ns5="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/base/1" xmlns="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/types/1" xmlns:ns6="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/EPtypes/1" xmlns:ns7="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/printform/1" xmlns:ns8="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/control99/1" xmlns:ns2="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/export/1" xmlns:ns3="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/pprf615types/1" xmlns:ns4="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/common/1">
<ns2:fcsNotificationEF schemeVersion="8.2">
<id>16950858</id>
<purchaseNumber>0111200000918000410</purchaseNumber>
<directDate>2018-07-05T16:55:52+03:00</directDate>
<docPublishDate>2018-07-05T16:55:59.225+03:00</docPublishDate>
<docNumber>№ИИ1</docNumber>
<href>
http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/notice/ea44/view/common-info.html?regNumber=0111200000918000410
</href>
"""

# pip install beautifulsoup4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
root = BeautifulSoup(xml_str, 'html.parser')

print(root.select_one('id').text)            # 16950858
print(root.select_one('href').text.strip())  # http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/notice/ea44/view/common-info.html?regNumber=0111200000918000410
```

Comment: есть возможность с таким же кодом парсить несколько файлов?

Comment: @NikitaAfanasev конечно, подставляйте в `root = BeautifulSoup(xml_str, 'html.parser')` разные содержимые файлов или пути к ним

Comment: а если файлы пополняются и нужно чтобы код парсил без изменения его содержимого

Comment: @NikitaAfanasev, создайте отдельный вопрос по вашей проблеме. В рамках вопроса опишите проблему. Пока сложно понять почему парсер может изменить содержимое, так не должно быть :)