# Как работать с xml для перевода слов и фраз?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, node.js, xml

никогда не работал с такой задачей, хотел бы узнать, как лучше это реализовать.

У меня есть пример кода xml в котором есть строки означают перевод слов и фраз на другой язык.

```
<Table>
    <Translation Original="Hello" Replace="Привет"/>
    <Translation Original="World" Replace="Мир"/>
</Table>
```

В данный момент я хочу написать функционал который будет принимать в себя подобную xml-ку как файл, переводить фразы в атрибуте Original и вставлять перевод в атрибут Replace.
Как сделать запрос на перевод я разберусь, но интересно как лучше реализовать тот самый парсер и вставку перевода. Уточню, что данных может быть много, примерно 1000-2000.

Было бы прекрасно если бы вы поделились подобным кодом или советами. Ищу примеры и стратегии для языкв JS на основе ноды или Python

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы `XML` данные преобразовать в некую структуру данных, к примеру в виде `JavaScript` объекта, для начала этот `XML` документ необходимо спарсить. Тут есть два пути реализации - либо использовать готовые решения, либо написать свой собственный алгоритм.

Из готовых решений, можно глянуть в [этом посте](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398419/trying-to-use-the-domparser-with-node-js/54096238#answer-55668667) (вариант для `JS`) и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/852237/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-xml-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0?rq=1) вариант для `Python`.
Касательно собственного подхода, - это уже более широкое поле для творчества в написании собственного алгоритма. Но если идти этим путем, я бы использовал частично [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) совместно с циклическим поиском.

Добавлю только что из самых критичных минусов использования готового решения, заключается в излишнем коде и стратегии парсинга, что в итоге может повлиять на производительность и время парсинга при больших объемах `XML файла`.